# Update single value in JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that looks like this:

```
 {
    "displayName": "",
    "Location": "Jacksonville",
    "directNumber": "+1 904-513-6504",
    "extension": "36504"
  }, 
  {
    "displayName": "Lawrence Curka",
    "Location": "Jacksonville",
    "directNumber": "+1 123-513-6508",
    "extension": "36508"
  },
  {
    "displayName": "Chris Brown",
    "Location": "Jacksonville",
    "directNumber": "+1 123-513-6511",
    "extension": "36511"
```

Basically I'm just trying to write a short Python script that will loop through the JSON, finds number that's free (meaning no displayName assigned) and if it's free add user to it (first name, last name).

But so far all examples I've found for JSON and Python is to append data but not updating individual key.

Here is Python I use that returns me all the free numbers from the JSON:

```
with open('file.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    user_count = 0

    for i in data:
        if i['displayName'] == "":
            print("Found Free Number: ", i['directNumber'])
            user_count += 1

    print("Free Number Count: ", user_count)
```

First object in JSON doesn't have user assigned (dispalyName).  Is it possible to just update just that value with name if it's empty/null?

Answer (score 0):

```
i['displayName'] = "Name Surname"

jsonFile.write(json.dumps(i))
```

Comment: This is what I get:      `json_file.write(json.dumps(i))
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable`

Comment: You need to open the file in write mode @user2011902